# Marker update position

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using [web2py](http://www.web2py.com/) on the server side to get google map position values:

```
  window.setInterval(function() {
                {{dic = get_position(1)}}
                var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng({{=dic['ID1']['lat']}}, {{=dic['ID1']['lon']}});
                markers[0].setPosition(newPos);
                testcounter++;}, 4000);
```

I want to change the position of a marker (`markers[0]`). The new position for marker is collected, but doesn't update its position on the map.

The data is collected from `get_position()` into a python dictionary of dicts and the data is ok.The parameter is a record id for testing purposes.

The html generated code, is ok too:

```
    window.setInterval(function() {
                var newPos = new google.maps.LatLng(-20.21353, -70.14904);
                markers[0].setPosition(newPos);
                testcounter++;}, 4000);
```

With testcounter I'm only checking the 4 secs loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of Python so I can't help with the back-end, but it looks like your best bet is to simply remove and re-instantiate the marker rather than attempting to alter it's position.

Alternately merely remove and replace the current marker? I.e:

```
markers[0].setMap(null);
markers[0].setMap(yourmap);
```

Though to be honest it would be strange if this solved the issue, but perhaps it needs to be reset in order to pick up the altered value.

Sorry to not be of more help.